# Use input tag instead of CharField in form in django

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I have django application with simple `ModelForm`:

```
class VideoUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = ['title', 'description','file']
```

I pass it to context in my view and than load it in template:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.title }}
   <br>
   {{ form.description }}
   <br>
   {{ form.file }}
   <br>
   <button type='submit'>Submit!</button>
</form>
```

Now I want to style my inputs, but I don't know how to do that. It should look something like:

```
<input type="text" class="title_input">
```

Just with additional linking to {{ form.title }} field.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom template filter

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def addclass(field, css):
    return field.as_widget(attrs={'class': css})
```

then apply it to the field
`{{ field|addclass:"classname" }}`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters

don't forget to load filter
`{% load <filename without py> %}`